# storing dynamic banner images for image slider from remote API before application starting in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How can I store my banner images from a remote API when ever a angular application starts and maintain that banner images in root scope variable so that it can be accessible in every controller scope.

Answer (score 0):

**step-1** create resolve section in router as given below in.

```js
var pcApp = angular.module('pcApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngTouch','ngAnimate']);
pcApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
c    
        resolve:{
        "check":function($location,$rootScope,$http){   
         $http.get("http://www.yourdomain.om/frontbanner").success(function (res) {
               
                $rootScope.saveBanner(res.data.details);
            }).error();
            
        }
      }         
    }).when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    });
});
```

**step-2** -create a function saveBanner in a global js file

```js
pcApp.controller('BodyController', function ($scope, $location, $rootScope) {
$rootScope.banner = {};   
if (localStorage.getItem('user_banner')) {
     $rootScope.banner = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user_banner'));
 }
$rootScope.saveBanner = function (lang) {
        $rootScope.banner = lang;
        localStorage.setItem('user_banner', JSON.stringify($rootScope.banner));
    };
  if (localStorage.getItem('user_banner')) {
        $rootScope.banner = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user_banner'));
    }
  
 });
```

**step-3** -call $roorScope.banner variable where  ever its needed.